# Pytest, change counter that is passed to markers dynamically

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-django, pytest-html, pytest-xdist

I am reading my test data from a Python file as follows.

//testdata.py -- its a list of sets.

```
TEST_DATA = [
(
{"test_scenario":"1"}, {"test_case_id":1}
),
(
{"test_scenario":"2"}, {"test_case_id":2}
)
]
```

Now I use this test data as part of a pytest test file.

```
// test.py
// import testdata

test_data = testdata.TEST_DATA   
start = 0

class TestOne():
    
     @pytest.mark.parametrize(("test_scenario,testcase_id"),test_data)
     @testcaseid.marktc[test_data[start][1]["test_case_id"]]
     def testfunction():
         global start
         start = start + 1
         // Doing test here.
```

Now when I print start, it changes its value continuoulsy. But when I try to retrieve the pytest results, I still keep getting start = 0 due to which my test case ID isnt being recorded properly.

Can I either

1. Pass marker from within the function.
2. Or is there a way to change the count of start dynamically in this example?

P.S. This is the best way that I am able to store my test data currently.

Here's how i have my testcaseid.marktc defined.
// testrailthingy.py

```
class testcaseid(object):

    @staticmethod
    def marktc(*ids):
        return pytest.mark.testrail(ids=ids)
```

Comment: the list is TEST_DATA and you are passing test_data. Assume both are same

Comment: Edited to show how I get the list.

Comment: where is `@testcaseid` defined

Comment: @gold_cy added how testcase_id.marktc annotation is defined.

Comment: not sure what `testrail` is, you're using some kind of plug-in it seems